# Redirect output to less from inside script

Tags: bash, io-redirection, less

I can redirect the output of a script to a logfile from inside the script with `exec`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > stdout.log 2>&1
echo hello world
```

Is it possible to redirect the output to `less` instead of a file? I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > >(less) 2>&1

# output some text
for (( i=1; i <= 500; i++ )); do echo "hello world $i"; done
```

but this fails in a strange way ... the less prompt is visible but you end back at the terminal.

I'd like to set this up a the start of the script (so it can be conditional, depending on arguments, tty, etc.).

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-use-less/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your script wait for the `less` child process, otherwise your script will terminate before it, and `less` will suddenly find itself outside the foreground process group, not able to read commands from the terminal or restore the terminal settings anymore.

Also, in order to prevent `less` for waiting forever for the end of its input, your script should close the pipe to it.

Putting all that together:

```
exec > >(less) 2>&1
trap 'exec >&- 2>&-; wait' EXIT
# >&- 2>&- => close stdout and stderr => cause EOF on less' stdin

seq 1 50000
# the rest of your script
```

But this is not very nice, not portable to most other shells, and relying on undocumented (and unreliable) behaviour of bash: the `wait` won't work fine if you have more than one `exec > >(...)` in your script, and it will also wait on other background processes started with `&`.

---

A better idea would be to have your script call itself, using an environment variable to avoid infinite recursion:

```
if [ ! "$CALLED_MYSELF" ]; then
    set -o pipefail # supported in bash, but not in all the shells  
    CALLED_MYSELF=1 "$0" "$@" 2>&1 | less
    exit
fi

seq 1 50000
# the rest of your script
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what's happening!

Answer (score 2):

Try just this (without the `exec` line):

```
for (( i=1; i <= 500; i++ )); do echo "hello world $i"; done | less
```

*(update)*

If you want to include the whole script, you can wrap the script with `{ ... }`

```
#!/bin/bash
{
# output some text
for (( i=1; i <= 500; i++)) do echo "hello world $i"; done

# whatever output you want...

} | less
```

Comment: Thank you but you this doesn't answer the question. I want to redirect the whole output of the script as shown in the first example, not just a line or part of it.

Comment: maybe run the script using the pipe?

Comment: i.e. `./script | less`

Comment: Thanks, while this would work I'd still prefer to set it up a the start of the script.

Comment: I agree with @SimonS for solutions.  I think he answered the question.  In shell scripting, there is always more than one way to do it.  If you don’t want to accept his suggestions, then you should research it yourself: [less howto](https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-use-less/), [man less](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html), [bash howto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html), and  [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) to name a few.